# Laravel 5.3 .env file Changed to local when I Push to remote server using git hooks

Tags: laravel

I have a github repo I always push there but currently working on a remote server when I push to remote Local .env file every time changes even though I put it on gitignore and the remote server does not take it from local but it Changes.

Comment: What is the output of `git ls-files .env`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you've already committed your `.env` file at some point.
Adding a file to `.gitignore` after you've committed it will not remove it from the repo.

What you will need to do is go to the root directory of your app and run:

```
git rm --cached .env
```

This should then remove it from your repo.

**NB** I haven't done this is a while but I'm pretty sure, as git basically thinks you've deleted the file, that it will delete it one the next pull. Before you do a pull I'd just make a copy of your .env on the remote server so you can easily swap it back. You should only need to do this the one time.

Hope this helps!